# Tensorflow.js: model loading error in bootstrap webpack example

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, bootstrap-5, tensorflow.js

I'm loading a JSON-formatted model in Tensorflow.js based on [the boostrap webpack example](https://github.com/twbs/examples/tree/main/webpack) on GitHub.

When I used Tensorflow.js without bootstrap in webpack, the following code works well in webpack or in an environment with script tag like
`src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"` without using node.js.

However, after I translated this code to the node environment on [the boostrap webpack example](https://github.com/twbs/examples/tree/main/webpack), I have this error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Variable with name conv2d/kernel was already registered
    at Engine.makeVariable (engine.ts:886:12)
    at Module.variable (variable.ts:43:2)
    at new LayerVariable (variables.ts:98:40)
    at Conv2D.addWeight (topology.ts:1315:3)
    at Conv2D.build (convolutional.ts:599:8)
    at eval (topology.ts:1013:12)
    at nameScope (common.ts:61:7)
    at Conv2D.apply (topology.ts:998:48)
    at Sequential.add (models.ts:557:3)
    at fromConfig (models.ts:1048:3)
```

What's the cause of this error?

Here is the detail.

main.js

```
import { prepare } from "./prediction.js";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", prepare);
...
```

prediction.js

```
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
import Plotly from "plotly.js-dist-min";

var TensorflowModels;
var predictConfigs;

export function prepare(){
  setTensorflowModels(pathOfRootFolder);
  ...
}

async function setTensorflowModels(pathOfRootFolder) {

  let Models = { p: 0 , wake: 0 , ct: 0 };
  let configs = { p: 0 , wake: 0 , ct: 0 };
  let path;
  // Read trained model of Tensorflow.js created by keras in Python.
  for (let key in Models) {
    path = [pathOfRootFolder, key, "model.json"].join("/");
    Models[key] = await tf.loadLayersModel(path);

    path = [pathOfRootFolder, key, "config.json"].join("/");
    configs[key] = await getConfig(path);
  }
  TensorflowModels = Models;
  predictConfigs = configs;

}
...
```

webpack.config.js

```
'use strict'

const path = require('path')
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/js/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  devServer:{
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    port: 8080,
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './src/index.html' })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            // Adds CSS to the DOM by injecting a `<style>` tag
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            // Interprets `@import` and `url()` like `import/require()` and will resolve them
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            // Loader for webpack to process CSS with PostCSS
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: () => [
                  autoprefixer
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            // Loads a SASS/SCSS file and compiles it to CSS
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is on line: `Models[key] = await tf.loadLayersModel(path);`. Wrap that line in `tf.tidy`. `tf.tidy` "Executes the provided function fn and after it is executed, cleans up all intermediate tensors allocated by fn except those returned by fn. fn must not return a Promise (async functions not allowed). The returned result can be a complex object.

Using this method helps avoid memory leaks. In general, wrap calls to operations in tf.tidy() for automatic memory cleanup." according to tfjs docs.

Comment: Additionally, you can try use `tf.disposeVariables()` before loading your model from it's path.

Comment: I appriciate your answer.

It reveals that seting of webpack is one on the cause of this issue.

Comment: I used scss, 'html-webpack-plugin' for bootstrap.
After I delete those settings in webpack.config.js.

The tensorflow code works!

I am using bootstrap just by css and js files.

Comment: I experienced the issue in nextjs application. The app also uses webpack but I highly doubt that it us webpack that was causing the problem. Fortunately, using the methods I stated earlier worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I agree with you that this is not the issue of interfarence between tensorlfow.js and webpack, but bootstrap webpack samples and tensorflow.js. I also sucessfuly worked on a tensorflow code in webpack.  I edited the question itself to concening of the bootstrap webpack sample.

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily solved the issue by modifiying webpack.config.js.

The "old" webpack.config.js contains the plugins and module parts for using Bootstrap.

When I remove those "plugins and module parts" in webpack.config.js.

Tensorflow.js works normally as before.

Now, I am using Bootstrap, just importing css and js files in HTML.